# All but last object in list changes its name

Tags: python, scripting

[.blend-file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kEYxZMBFr42QghlaiVTr7GUD4Lz7TCks)

I have this code which creates an object, gives the object a new unique name and then adds the object to a list. After the object is added to the list I unlink it from the scene.

```
print('start')
ok_boards = []
clean_up_but_keep('MESH', ['BackupBoard', 'Plane'])
for x in range(3):
    b = get_ok_table()
    b.name = "board" + str(x)
    ok_boards.append(b)
    bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].objects.unlink(b)

print(ok_boards[0])
print(ok_boards[1])
print(ok_boards[2])
```

But when I print the list i get this:
[image]

How do I get the objects to stay in the list just as they where added?

(The code is making a copy of an object called BackupBoard and gives it the name Board. Therefore, the object that get_ok_table() brings has the name Board every round in the loop)

Comment: Half of the code is unknown (`get_ok_table()` and `clean_up_but_keep()`), so it's hard to say.

Comment: I have added the .blend file to the main post now.

The main goal is to create working tables from the BackupBoard by extracting 4 legs from the board and then test if the board will stand up with weights on specific spots on the table. If the table passes the test I want to append it to a list and this is where the problem emerges.

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend file uploads. Also, if it's possible, please include any relevant code in the question itself. The less barriers to getting to see the full code, the more likely someone will answer.